# I want to change the location of redo files on standby db

Tags: oracle, rman, dataguard, standby

my db is generating redofiles to a certain path, lets call it 'old/path', and i want to move it to a new path, lets call it 'new/path' in oracle

can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop the standby:

   ```
   SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE CANCEL;
   ```
2. Identify the location of the redo logs:

   ```
   SQL> SELECT MEMBER FROM V$LOGFILE;
   ```
3. Copy those files to the desired location:

   ```
   cp filename path/to/folder
   ```
4. In case `standby_file_management` is set to `auto`, switch it to the manual mode:

   ```
   SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
   SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET STANDBY_FILE_MANAGEMENT = MANUAL;
   ```
5. Rename log files:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE 'path/to/old_filename' TO 'path/to/new_filename';
   ```
6. Mount the database:

   ```
   STARTUP MOUNT
   ```
7. Revert `standby_file_management`  to `auto`:

   ```
   SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET STANDBY_FILE_MANAGEMENT = AUTO;
   ```
8. Start the standby:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE USING CURRENT LOGFILE 
    DISCONNECT;
   ```

Comment: An explanation would improve your answer

Comment: @RohitGupta, the commands are pretty much self explanatory. If you're having some difficulty understanding, please feel free to ask, I'll be more than willing to help.

Comment: You misunderstand, my comment was to make your answer better for future visitors. Code only answers don't necessarily help them.  See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)